# error on compiling statically linked library created in Qt

Tags: c++, qt-creator

we have created a statically linked library in Qt.On compiling the library we are getting errors...like QImage: no such file or directory and why start timer etc...

Answer (score 2):

If you can compile some parts with errors but only get compile errors when you `#include` Qt parts in the QtGui module, then you may need to look at your .pro file and make sure that you DON'T have `QT -= gui`.

Comment: Actually I compile with QT -= gui as well, but using #include <QtGui/QImage> instead. Qt version is 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [the documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qimage.html)?

Did you `#include <QImage>`?

Is your compiler set up to find the Qt libraries?

Answer (score 0):

At first you should create your `Makefile` with `qmake -project` in your src directory, then use `make` command. After it, you can manipulate it manually.